# error in eclipse with android:windowElevation

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a problem with Eclipse

[image]

This is my error that appears in the console:

```
(\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:146: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.)
```

And further information:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Unparsed aapt error(s)! Check the console for output.   appcompat_v7        line 1  Android ADT Problem
The method onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem) of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method   MainActivity.java   /9/src/com/example  line 24 Java Problem
The method onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method MainActivity.java   /9/src/com/example  line 17 Java Problem
The method onCreate(Bundle) of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method  MainActivity.java   /9/src/com/example  line 11 Java Problem
The method getMenuInflater() is undefined for the type MainActivity MainActivity.java   /9/src/com/example  line 19 Java Problem
The import android.support.v7 cannot be resolved    MainActivity.java   /9/src/com/example  line 3  Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  MainActivity.java   /9/src/com/example  line 13 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  MainActivity.java   /9/src/com/example  line 19 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  MainActivity.java   /9/src/com/example  line 29 Java Problem
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'. styles.xml  /9/res/values   line 7  Android AAPT Problem
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.  styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line 75 Android AAPT Problem
ActionBarActivity cannot be resolved to a type  MainActivity.java   /9/src/com/example  line 8  Java Problem
ActionBarActivity cannot be resolved to a type  MainActivity.java   /9/src/com/example  line 12 Java Problem
ActionBarActivity cannot be resolved to a type  MainActivity.java   /9/src/com/example  line 32 Java Problem
```

How can fix that?

Comment: udpate the build tools to latest version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build your project against highest API you want to support, so set your target SDK for this project to be 21 or 22 (if you got that SDK downloaded already)